# How to add responsiveness to a flexbox div element without a css file

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, media-queries

as the title suggests, I have been wondering if you can add responsiveness to a div flexbox element without using an external css file, but putting it directly into the div style. My code looks as follows and on desktop versions the text should be on the right side of the image, but in mobile/tablet versions I want to put it below the image. How do I add responsiveness, as right now it overflows the elements when viewed on mobile.

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap; margin-bottom: 20px;">
     <img src="image on the left side">
     <div style="flex-direction: column;">
        <b>title to the right of the image</b>
        <p>description under title</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Media Queries are using `@media` rule to add the CSS properties, and [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#:%7E:text=The%20%40media%20CSS%20at%2Drule,the%20content%20is%20being%20used.):

> The `@media` CSS at-rule can be used to apply part of a style sheet based on the result of one or more media queries. With it, you specify a media query and a block of CSS to apply to the document if and only if the media query matches the device on which the content is being used.

**So, it's impossible** to use it without either an internal `<style></style>` tag in your `<head></head>` or a separate stylesheet file.

Answer (score 0):

"Without an external CSS file": Yes, by putting the according CSS rules in a `<style></style>` tag in the HTML document itself (preferably in the `<head>`, but it also works in the `body`)

Example:

```html
<style>
  .a {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .b {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
   }
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .a {
      flex-direction: column;
    }
  }
</style>

<div class="a">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/300x200/fa0">
  <div class="b">
    <b>title to the right of the image</b>
    <p>description under title</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`min-width` and `flex-grow` could be an hint :

```html
<div 
   style="
   display: flex; 
   flex-direction: row; 
   flex-wrap: wrap; 
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   ">
   
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x100/f5a" 
  style="
  flex-grow:1; 
  min-width:320px;  
  ">
  
  <div 
  style="
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow:1;
  background:lightgray;  
  min-width: 60%;
  justify-content:center;
  padding:0.5em;
  ">
    <b>title to the right of the image</b>
    <p>description under title</p>
  </div>
</div>
```